# Newtonsoft Json.NET JSONProperty() needs to be any random number

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i can't figure out how to create a JSONProperty with any number.
For example my JSON that i receive looks like this from the start:

`{ "255710": { "success": true,...`

The specific Problem that i have is, that the first number, in this case 255710, can be any random number. Therefore i can not deserialize it so easily.

I have tried it with:

```
[JsonProperty("*")] [JsonProperty()] and [JsonProperty("")]
```

but i'm running out of ideas here.

Is there any smart solution for this problem?
Im thankfull for every help.

Comment: You should serialize into a `Dictionary<int, YourClass>`.

Comment: If your JSON is as described, then the dictionary would be the root element.  Therefore, Serge's answer seems like it should work to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var json ="{ \"255710\": { \"success\": true}}";

var dict=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,SuccessClass>>(json);
    
public class SuccessClass
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success {get; set;}
}
```

how to use

```
var success=dict["255710"].Success; // true
```

or you can use int if you like it more

```
var dict=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int,SuccessClass>>(json);
var success=dict[255710].Success; //true
```

or if you don't know a key name

```
var key=dict.Keys.First();
    
var success=dict[key].Success; // true

// or if you don't need a key
var successObj=dict.Values.First(); //the whole sucess class
var success=dict.Values.First().Success; //true
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to parse this JSON. One way is to use JObject and skip the first element then, for convenience, convert to dynamic as follows:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;

string json = "{ \"123\": { \"success\": true, \"other\": \"the string\" } }";

JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var dyn = obj.First.First.ToObject<dynamic>();
Console.WriteLine($"dyn.success: {dyn.success}");
Console.WriteLine($"dyn.other: {dyn.other}");
```

This will output:

```
dyn.success: True
dyn.other: the string
```

I've skipped the first element since it's random, but you should ask yourself if it is really random. Isn't it an id for a method call? If it is, then you can more easily convert it into a dictionary and just read the key with the ID.

And you may also use a strong typed class for the result if it is known to you.

Comment: Dictionary is laying under hood of dynamic type. So a dictionary is more effective since code goes to the second layer immediately.

Comment: @Serge it's just a matter of convenience. Since the structure of the object "inside" the "random" key is known it's a nonissue after all: just use a `SuccessClass` as you did :-)